# Should I get travel insurance for a trip booked as a mileage award?

Tags: air-travel, insurance, pregnancy

My wife and I are planning a trip as a "babymoon," and are hoping to fly using award flights as we have more than enough miles - but as my wife is pregnant I am nervous that something might happen and we may need to cancel the flight. As a result, I'm thinking that travel insurance is a good idea. This is generally the advice that I have gotten from everyone - whenever traveling with someone pregnant, get the travel insurance when it's offered. However, if I am booking flights as awards, is the travel insurance still worth it? If I need to cancel a flight which was an award, but it has insurance, will I get the miles back in the same way that I would get the money back from a revenue ticket?

Comment: It probably would have helped to mention that you are flying United. Cancel fee (presuming no status) is $200/person.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your airline's rules for redepositing miles if you cancel the trip... check this before booking.

In the most common case airlines charge a fee to cancel the trip and redeposit the miles, and insurance often covers this fee.

If you are a frequent traveller with elite status the airline may have a policy of waiving the redeposit fee.

A good source for more information is [here](http://thepointsguy.com/2013/12/should-i-purchase-trip-insurance-to-cover-an-award-redeposit-fee/)